Multiple `bpf_clone_redirect` send packet only to last address
I am trying to create a simple BPF filter for tc to duplicate all packets arriving on a specific interface to two (or more) lookback addresses. The following code works with one address, but if I add a second bpf_clone_redirect then the packets are only received on the second address and not on the first. tcpdump -nevvi lo shows all packets destined to both.
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/pkt_cls.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include "bpf_helpers.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define CLONE_1 2130706689
#define CLONE_2 2130706690

#define LOOPBACK_INTERFACE_INDEX 1

struct l3_fields
{
    __u32 saddr;
    __u32 daddr;
};

struct l4_fields
{
    __u16 sport;
    __u16 dport;
};

struct udphdr
{
    __be16 source;
    __be16 dest;
    __be16 len;
    __sum16 check;
};

SEC("tc_eth0")
int dns_redirect_eth0_loopback(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    struct iphdr *ip4h;
    struct l3_fields l3_original_fields;
    struct l3_fields l3_new_fields;
    struct l4_fields l4_original_fields;
    struct l4_fields l4_new_fields;

    // redirect packet to loopback interface
    __u32 ifindex = LOOPBACK_INTERFACE_INDEX;

    // Checking if eth headers are incomplete
    if (data + sizeof(*eth) > data_end)
    {
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;
    }

    // Allowing IPV6 packets to passthrough without modification
    if (ntohs(eth->h_proto) != ETH_P_IP)
    {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }

    // Checking if IP headers are incomplete
    if (data + sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*ip4h) > data_end)
    {
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;
    }

    ip4h = data + sizeof(*eth);
    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, sizeof(*eth) + offsetof(struct iphdr, saddr), &l3_original_fields, sizeof(l3_original_fields));
    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*ip4h), &l4_original_fields, sizeof(l4_original_fields));
    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, sizeof(*eth) + offsetof(struct iphdr, saddr), &l3_new_fields, sizeof(l3_new_fields));
    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*ip4h), &l4_new_fields, sizeof(l4_new_fields));

    // Change destination address to LOOPBACK
    l3_new_fields.daddr = htonl(CLONE_1);

    bpf_skb_store_bytes(skb, sizeof(*eth) + offsetof(struct iphdr, saddr), &l3_new_fields, sizeof(l3_new_fields), BPF_F_RECOMPUTE_CSUM);

    __u64 l3sum = bpf_csum_diff((__u32 *)&l3_original_fields, sizeof(l3_original_fields), (__u32 *)&l3_new_fields, sizeof(l3_new_fields), 0);
    __u64 l4sum = bpf_csum_diff((__u32 *)&l4_original_fields, sizeof(l4_original_fields), (__u32 *)&l4_new_fields, sizeof(l4_new_fields), l3sum);

    int csumret = bpf_l4_csum_replace(skb, sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*ip4h) + offsetof(struct udphdr, check), 0, l4sum, BPF_F_PSEUDO_HDR);
    csumret |= bpf_l3_csum_replace(skb, sizeof(*eth) + offsetof(struct iphdr, check), 0, l3sum, 0);

    if (csumret)
    {
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;
    }

    int ret = bpf_clone_redirect(skb, LOOPBACK_INTERFACE_INDEX, 1);

    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, sizeof(*eth) + offsetof(struct iphdr, saddr), &l3_original_fields, sizeof(l3_original_fields));
    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*ip4h), &l4_original_fields, sizeof(l4_original_fields));

    // Change destination address to LOOPBACK
    l3_new_fields.daddr = htonl(CLONE_2);

    bpf_skb_store_bytes(skb, sizeof(*eth) + offsetof(struct iphdr, saddr), &l3_new_fields, sizeof(l3_new_fields), BPF_F_RECOMPUTE_CSUM);

    l3sum = bpf_csum_diff((__u32 *)&l3_original_fields, sizeof(l3_original_fields), (__u32 *)&l3_new_fields, sizeof(l3_new_fields), 0);
    l4sum = bpf_csum_diff((__u32 *)&l4_original_fields, sizeof(l4_original_fields), (__u32 *)&l4_new_fields, sizeof(l4_new_fields), l3sum);

    csumret = bpf_l4_csum_replace(skb, sizeof(*eth) + sizeof(*ip4h) + offsetof(struct udphdr, check), 0, l4sum, BPF_F_PSEUDO_HDR);
    csumret |= bpf_l3_csum_replace(skb, sizeof(*eth) + offsetof(struct iphdr, check), 0, l3sum, 0);

    if (csumret)
    {
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;
    }

    ret &= bpf_clone_redirect(skb, LOOPBACK_INTERFACE_INDEX, 1);

    return ret;
}

P.S. the code is heavily based on other things I found online, but the principle should work.
Edit: A trace I got with pwru:
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->192.168.3.100:26090(udp) inet_gro_receive
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->192.168.3.100:26090(udp) udp4_gro_receive
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->192.168.3.100:26090(udp) udp_gro_receive
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->192.168.3.100:26090(udp) gro_normal_one
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->192.168.3.100:26090(udp) tcf_classify_ingress
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->192.168.3.100:26090(udp) skb_ensure_writable
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     skb_ensure_writable
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     inet_proto_csum_replace_by_diff
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     skb_ensure_writable
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     skb_clone
0xffff967443545c00 0   <empty>:0        0          0               0         0x0000 0     0     :0->:0()                                      __copy_skb_header
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     skb_ensure_writable
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     pskb_expand_head
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     skb_release_data
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     skb_headers_offset_update
0xffff967443545c00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     __bpf_redirect
0xffff967443545c00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     dev_forward_skb
0xffff967443545c00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     __dev_forward_skb
0xffff967443545c00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     skb_scrub_packet
0xffff967443545c00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     eth_type_trans
0xffff967443545c00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0              lo:1       0x0800 65536 868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     netif_rx_internal
0xffff967443545c00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0              lo:1       0x0800 65536 868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     enqueue_to_backlog
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.1:26090(udp)     skb_ensure_writable
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_ensure_writable
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     inet_proto_csum_replace_by_diff
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_ensure_writable
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_clone
0xffff967443545400 0   <empty>:0        0          0               0         0x0000 0     0     :0->:0()                                      __copy_skb_header
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_ensure_writable
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     pskb_expand_head
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_release_data
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_headers_offset_update
0xffff967443545400 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     __bpf_redirect
0xffff967443545400 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     dev_forward_skb
0xffff967443545400 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     __dev_forward_skb
0xffff967443545400 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_scrub_packet
0xffff967443545400 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  882   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     eth_type_trans
0xffff967443545400 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0              lo:1       0x0800 65536 868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     netif_rx_internal
0xffff967443545400 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0              lo:1       0x0800 65536 868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     enqueue_to_backlog
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     ip_rcv_core
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     udp_v4_early_demux
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     ip_route_input_noref
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     ip_route_input_rcu
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     ip_route_input_slow
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     fib_validate_source
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     ip_local_deliver
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     nf_hook_slow
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 868   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     ip_local_deliver_finish
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     ip_protocol_deliver_rcu
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     raw_local_deliver
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     udp_rcv
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     __udp4_lib_rcv
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     __icmp_send
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     __ip_options_echo
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     security_skb_classify_flow
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     __xfrm_decode_session
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     decode_session4
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     security_xfrm_decode_session
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     kfree_skb
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 65536 848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_release_head_state
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     skb_release_data
0xffff967443545a00 0   <empty>:0        4026531992 0            enp1s0:2     0x0800 9000  848   192.168.3.101:26090->127.0.1.2:26090(udp)     kfree_skbmem

Clearly the second packet goes through a lot more than the first, though I don't know enough about it to diagnose.

So all packets are received on the same destination IP address, but are they cloned? That is, do you see twice as many packets received as you sent?

Yes, I receive one copy on 127.0.1.1 and one on 127.0.1.2 according to tcpdump. However, the receiving program only sees packets on 127.0.1.2 and not on 127.0.1.1.

If tcpdump sees both destination IP addresses, then the issue is probably not with the BPF program. What does your receiving program look like? Did you try tracing the 127.0.1.1 packet to see where it's dropped?

@pchaigno My apologies it took me so long to get back to this. From further testing it seems that clone_redirect is not executed immediately, but at the end of the program. In particular, changing the skb daddr after clone_redirect stops the receiving program from getting the packets, even if the second clone_redirect is never called. I.e., even commenting out everything after the second skb_store_bytes does not work.

I tried tracing with pwru but the traces for the two addresses are identical, so I am not sure what is happening there. Curiously, tcpdump always shows that everything is fine.

You can't do multiple redirects for a packet from one program. This also applies for XDP as well. This limitation might be lifted in the future, but no-one adressed it yet.
The related issue and possible solution for XDP (not for the TC hook but in principle it might be applies for that as well): https://www.spinics.net/lists/xdp-newbies/msg02552.html
A possibe workaround could be passing the packet into userspace with bpf_ringbuf, modify it and inject it back to the network on AF_PACKET. This might introduce 50-150 microsec extra latency.
Edit: The above applies for XDP only. As @pchaigno pointed out this is doable with TC. You have to create a map with the interfaces you want to redirect the packet. Then use bpf_for_each_map_elem to iterate the map with a callback function which does the actual redirect bpf_clone_redirect.

AFAIK, you can do multiple redirects and that's what Cilium does for its multicast implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79055081/multiple-bpf-clone-redirect-send-packet-only-to-last-address/79065581#79065581. Here with the bpf_for_each_map_elem, but my colleague tells me it worked with a normal bounded loop as well before.

My bad, indeed possible: https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/ebb4c47a36095562930a2c8e85cf0861da153c27/bpf/lib/mcast.h#L433

Ah, thanks! That's the link I intended to paste :facepalm:

However, as noted, bpf_for_each_map_elem isn't the only way to do this, and the OP's approach should work as far as I can see.
